# I can't understand vectors in Unity(c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Of the following code, in last second line of code, while using the AddForce() method, I can't understand why there is a need for doing such a long process of **finding the direction and the magnitude and multiplying them to make it a Vector2 argument** while we can do it just by giving the argument as **new Vector2(*an x component, a y component*)**. I can't understand the purpose of doing it?

OR perhaps, I don't understand what does **new Vector2(*an x component, a y component*)** mean.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// A teddy bear
/// </summary>
public class TeddyBear : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Start is called before the first frame update
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        // get the teddy bear moving
        const float MinImpulseForce = 3f;
        const float MaxImpulseForce = 5f;
        float magnitude = Random.Range(MinImpulseForce, MaxImpulseForce);
        float angle = Random.Range(Mathf.PI / 2, Mathf.PI);
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle));
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(
            direction * magnitude , ForceMode2D.Impulse);

    }
    
}
```

Comment: "while we can do it just by giving the argument as new Vector2(an x component, a y component)" Show me how then! Reproduce the same behaviour as this code using that constructor, without doing the "long process".

Comment: @Sweeper I mean, like, when we do new Vector2(2,3), the force will be applied in a certain direction and that DIRECTION WILL BE BASED THE FORCE DISTRIBUTION which depends on the x and y components we provided. So I believe, the direction will be determined automatically(without giving an angle or something) according to the force in both the components. So, why there's a need to find an angle and direction sepearately.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about vectors, but about the distribution of pseudo-random numbers. When you use `Random.Range` the numbers are (very close to) distributed uniformly on that range. You will see that not all vectors are possible. In fact the possible vectors exists in a particular shape, and **what is important is the shape in which the possible vectors can exist.** *And their distribution in that shape.*

They could have generated a random `x` and a random `y` coordinates, which would have ensured that the vectors would be equally distributed in those variables. Which means that the possible vectors can exist in a **square** (or a rectangle if the ranges for `x` and `y` were different).

Then the probability of getting vectors on each direction and distance would not be uniform (for example, the vectors could be further from the center in the directions of the corners of the square). Another way to think about it is that `x` and `y` are independent, but as a result there is a correlation between `angle` and `distance`.

Instead they want to generate the number in polar coordinates, in other words by an `angle` and a `distance` (which they call `magnitud` in this example), so that they know that the vector are distributed equally in those variables. Which also means that the possible vectors can exist in a **circle**. *To reiterate, this ensure there are no correlation between `angle` or `distance`.*

That is what you see here:

```
float magnitude = Random.Range(MinImpulseForce, MaxImpulseForce);
float angle = Random.Range(Mathf.PI / 2, Mathf.PI);
```

Well… Actually, that is not the whole range of angles, so this is not a full circle but a **sector of a circle**. And presumably `MinImpulseForce` might not be zero (It is `3f` actually), so this is actually a **sector of <strike>a ring</strike> an annulus** (a sector of a 2D donut). *To reiterate: that shape in which the possible vectors can exist what is important.*

---

Well, then since they decided to use polar coordinantes, and the vector constructor takes x and y, they do a polar to cartesian conversion. Which would be like this:

```
new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * magnitude;
```

*Except they multiply by `magnitude` further down in the example.*

That is the same as this:

```
new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle) * magnitude, Mathf.Sin(angle) * magnitude);
```

But using vector-scalar multiplication is shorter.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a very complex explanation for me. I simply have a doubt like, when we do new Vector2(2,3), the force will be applied in a certain direction and that DIRECTION WILL BE BASED THE FORCE DISTRIBUTION which depends on the x and y components we provided. So, I believe, the direction will be determined automatically (without giving an angle or something) according to the force in both the components. So, why there's a need to find an angle and direction separately

Comment: @Rohan You are correct that the direction will be based on the x and y components. What if we don't want that? What if we want the direction and magnitude of the force to be independently distributed? That is apparently what the author of the code wanted.

Comment: @Rohan Yes, but what if the designer wants to control the direction? If the designer wants the direction to be between a range of angles, then it is easier to define that range of angles, pick and angle between them and then do the conversion to x and y. That is ultimately predicated on what the designer wants to do. Even even the designer does not care what the angle is, but care if the all angles are equally likely it makes sense to generate and angle… Because the distribution is different. I wish I had a visual for you, but I don't have one at hand.

Comment: @Theraot I may have understood what you're trying to say here. Let me see if what I understood works for me in the future or not? Thanks though. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Nicely explained! .. just wanted to add: you can also simply use [`var direction = Random.insideUnitCircle.normalized`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitCircle.html) which will have about the same results